# iPhone Development: Manually track time in active screen using Google Analytics

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics

I'm currently unable to use `GAITrackedViewController` because the application I'm working on doesn't use `UIViewControllers`, only `UIViews` in a UIWindow.

I use `[tracker sendView:@"Home Screen"];` to send the active screen, but it doesn't track time.

Is there a manual way to manually send the active time in a `UIView` using Google Analytics?

Comment: You should really add at least one viewcontroller.

Comment: Thanks for the reply James, I thought there could be another way to do it without a ViewController.